# Sorting words using bubblesort

Tags: c

I am trying to sort words using bubble sort but cannot make out what the error is. My swapping works but cannot sort it correctly.

```
void sortByWord (struct node** head) {
    struct node* temp  = (*head);
    struct node* temp2 = (*head);

    int i;
    int j;
    int counter = 0;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        temp = nodeGetNextNode(temp);
        counter++;
    }
    for( i = 1; i<counter; i++)
    {
        temp2=(*head);
        for(j = 1; j<counter-1;j++)
        {
            if(wordCmpare(temp2,nodeGetNextNode(temp2))>0)
            {
                swap(head,temp2,nodeGetNextNode(temp2));
                continue;
            }
        }
        temp2 = nodeGetNextNode(temp2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried *debugging* this?

Comment: If you say something is not working, you should show the result, the result you expect and all the code pertaining to that part of error.

Answer (score 1):

The `continue` continues the inner loop. Maybe you need to add a goto or a flag.

```
  for( i = 1; i<counter; i++)
  {
        temp2=(*head);
        for(j = 1; j<counter-1;j++)
        {
            if(wordCmpare(temp2,nodeGetNextNode(temp2))>0)
            {
                swap(head,temp2,nodeGetNextNode(temp2));
                goto endOfLoop;
            }
        }

        temp2 = nodeGetNextNode(temp2); // BTW: This line does nothing useful
endOfLoop:       
        ;
  }
```

This is the flag part:

```
  for( i = 1; i<counter; i++)
    {
    temp2=(*head);
    boolean flag = false;
    for(j = 1; j<counter-1;j++)
    {
        if(wordCmpare(temp2,nodeGetNextNode(temp2))>0)
        {
            swap(head,temp2,nodeGetNextNode(temp2));
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (flag) continue;
    temp2 = nodeGetNextNode(temp2); // BTW: This line does nothing useful
}
```

Comment: C doesn't have `continue` with labels.

Comment: To do something like this you need `goto label;`.

Comment: @interjay Duh. Changed it.

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin It's a classic bubble sort. It just works this way and has for 50 years (or so). It shows a weakness in C in dealing with breaking out of nested loops. Just compare the two versions. They both suck. Feel free to post better code.

Comment: `qsort(...)` - if something has been done the same way for 50 years, maybe it's time to break out of the copy&paste loop.